# How do I display data sent from the express router in my react-component?

Tags: express, reactjs

Routing code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {username: req.session['passport']['user']['username']});
}
```

I'd like to display this username object in my react component, something like this:

```
var Account = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        {username}
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Obviously, the above results in a 'username' is undefined error.  How does one go about accessing this data supplied by router in a react component?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common pattern is to fetch the data from within your component when it mounts. For example, imagine some helper that interfaces with your API that returns a promise. Then you can do something like:

```
var Account = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      username: ''
    };
  },

  componentWillMount: function() {
    APIHelper.get('/').then(function(response) {
      this.setState({
        username: response.username
      });
    });
  },

  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.username}
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```